# Failed to load native library grpc_csharp_ext.x86.dll while running Azure Function in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, exception, azure-functions, grpc

lately I have encountered a following problem. Azure Function that is run in Visual Studio always throws an exception:

> System.IO.IOException   HResult=0x80131620   Message=Error loading
>   native library
>   "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\2.16.0\cli\grpc_csharp_ext.x86.dll"
>   Source=Grpc.Core   StackTrace:    at
>   Grpc.Core.Internal.UnmanagedLibrary..ctor(String[]
>   libraryPathAlternatives)    at
>   Grpc.Core.Internal.NativeExtension.LoadUnmanagedLibrary()    at
>   Grpc.Core.Internal.NativeExtension.LoadNativeMethods()    at
>   Grpc.Core.Internal.NativeExtension..ctor()    at
>   Grpc.Core.Internal.NativeExtension.Get()    at
>   Grpc.Core.GrpcEnvironment.GrpcNativeInit()    at
>   Grpc.Core.GrpcEnvironment..ctor()    at
>   Grpc.Core.GrpcEnvironment.AddRef()    at
>   Grpc.Core.Server..ctor(IEnumerable`1 options)    at
>   Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Grpc.GrpcServer..ctor(FunctionRpcBase
>   serviceImpl) in
>   C:\azure-webjobs-sdk-script\src\WebJobs.Script.Grpc\Server\GrpcServer.cs:line
>   24

The file that is supposedly missing is at its place of course. I've tried to reinstall Azure Function Tools and Visual Studio and nothing helped. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT1:

The problem seems to be caused by non-english characters in the path to the library. I've just created another account without them and suddenly everything started to work.

Comment: Have you tried to remove the directory `%localappdata%\AzureFunctionsTools` and make VS download the cli again?

Comment: Yep, I've also tried to reset my PC to factory settings. Neither of those helped.

Answer (score 2):

from the point that the root cause of error is because of the non-english characters in the path to the library, you can consider to rename path of your user profile.

To do so, here is the steps

- Log out and login with another Administrator user to your PC
- open command prompt by <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> then type `cmd`
- type `wmic useraccount get name, sid` and get `SID` of your profile
- type `regedit` under start menu, right click on it and select `Run as Administrator`
- Go under `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\YOUR_SID_HERE`
- Double Click on `ProfileImagePath` and change the value data according to your need (you can close Registry Editor)
- go under USER PROFILES folder (`%USERPROFILE%\..\`) and change the path of your user profile accordingly
- Restart your computer